# Upload images in placeholder dropzone?

Tags: javascript, upload, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to upload my images as below:

```
     var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('product-image-drpzone'), {
        uploadMultiple: false,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif',
        parallelUploads: 4,
        maxFiles: 4,
        url: Urls.products.image_upload
    });

    myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('cloud_name', '');
        formData.append('api_key',);
        formData.append('api_secret', '');
        formData.append('timestamp', Date.now() / 1000 | 0);
        formData.append('upload_preset', 'gi7szvel');
    });
    myDropzone.on('success', function (file, response) {
        _this.imagesArr.push(response.public_id);
        console.log('Success! Cloudinary public ID is', response.public_id);
    });
```

My page

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone col-sm-8" id="product-image-drpzone">
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                </div>
                <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>Drag & Drop Product images here to upload, or
                     <a class="btn-choose-file btn-link" id="btn-upload">browse.</a>
                </span>

                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-sm-4 dropzone-previews">
                <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
                 <img src="holder.js/100x100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
               <img src="holder.js/100x100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 append_bottom10"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
               <img src="holder.js/100x100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
                 <img src="holder.js/100x100">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**How do i upload my images in the given placeholders with dropzone?**

I tried using dz-preview to point to the images.

Comment: Can you add the html? It would be easier to provide an answer this way.

Comment: @wallek876 just added the html

Answer (score 2):

According to the dropzone documentation when you select a different container this should have the class `dropzone-previews`, but I think there must be some error with because the dropzone css doesn't seem to target this specific class.

The only work around I can think of is to modify the dropzone css file. Just search all the occurrences of `.dropzone .dz-preview` in the dropzone css file and replace with `.dropzone-previews .dz-preview`.

Then you can change the placeholders with the dropzone previews like this.

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone col-sm-8" id="product-image-drpzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
      <span>Drag & Drop Product images here to upload, or
            <a class="btn-choose-file btn-link" id="btn-upload">browse.</a>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="previews" class="col-sm-4 dropzone-previews">
    <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
      <img src="holder.js/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
      <img src="holder.js/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
      <img src="holder.js/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 dz-preview drp-image">
      <img src="holder.js/100x100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('product-image-drpzone'), {
  uploadMultiple: false,
  acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif',
  parallelUploads: 4,
  maxFiles: 4,
  url: Urls.products.image_upload,
  previewsContainer: '#previews',
  thumbnailWidth: 100,
  thumbnailHeight: 100,

  init: function() {

    // This adds the bootstrap class col-sm-6 to the dropzone preview
    var classIndex = this.options.previewTemplate.indexOf('dz-preview');
    this.options.previewTemplate = this.options.previewTemplate.slice(0, classIndex) + 'col-sm-6 ' + this.options.previewTemplate.slice(classIndex);

    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
      $('.drp-image').first().remove();
    });
  }
});
```

css:

```
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.drp-image > img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Yo can see a demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/umqieD2PeW4vFcsQYLY3?p=preview).

Note that I just added the part of the code that affects the previews